# не могу понять как работает команда continue в цикле while python. Заранее благодарю за поддержку

Tags: python, while, continue

добрые и умные люди) не могу понять как воспользоваться continue, что бы пропустить символ  в питоне. Стоит задача разбить строку на две части, да так чтобы вторая часть начиналась с символа 'e', но не включала его

```
numm = '123e-21'
res=''
res2=''
add = True
for i in numm:  
  while add:
  
    if i!='e':
      res+=i
      break
    else:
      add= False
      break
  while not add:
    res2+=i
    break

print('Мантисса: ', res)
print('порядок этого числа: ', res2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Для выполнения задачи достаточно воспользоваться методом split()

```
numm = '123e-21'
res, res2 = numm.split('e')
print('Мантисса: ', res)
print('порядок этого числа: ', res2)
```

По поводу continue в цикле while. Цель continue остановить выполнение текущей итерации в моменте появления continue и перейти к следующей итерации. Ниже решение этой задачи с циклом while и continue. Оно не оптимально. Чисто для учебных целей.

```
numm = '123e-21'
n = len(numm)
passed_e = False
res = ''
res2 = ''
i = 0
while i < n:
    v = numm[i]
    if v == 'e':
        passed_e = True
        i += 1
        continue
    if passed_e:
        res2 += v
        i += 1
        continue
    i += 1
    res += v
print('Мантисса: ', res)
print('порядок этого числа: ', res2)
```

Comment: спасибо за пример, но к сожалению не смог реализовать это в своем коде, или бесконецный цикл получается или не могу перескочить этот символ(. Не судите, только начал учиться программированию)

Comment: @АлександрШ.Дело в том, что для решения этой задачи не нужны ни while, ни continue. Достаточно цикла for, если вас не устраивает решение через метод split(). Специально для вас добавил это искусственное и не оптимальное решение. Чисто в учебных целях.

Comment: спасибо! очень круто! если не секрет как долго вы в программировании? и на сколько тяжело было в начале? извините за то что отнимаю времени, просто не могу понять свои трудности, в чем причины , или все через это проходили?

Comment: @АлександрШ.Всё индивидуально. Начинайте с основ. Найдите бесплатный курс в удобном формате для начинающих(статьи, видео или книги) и идите от простого к сложному. Советую курсы на stepic.org. Если что-то непонятно ищите в интернете. О том же continue можно  найти много статей через поисковик. Всего вы никогда не узнаете. Так что просто регулярно учитесь в меру своих сил. Параллельно пробуйте писать свои скриптики на основе пройденных материалов. А всякими сравнениями и рассуждениями не забивайте голову. Нравится - прогайте. Нет - забейте, чтобы не тратить время и силы без удовольствия.

Comment: спасибо, буду долбить, упорство есть слава богу и желание стать программистом тоже